# Set content / value of TextArea using TextAreaFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to use MVC4's `Html.TextAreaFor()` method to create a textarea with default text inside it. With normal HTML I would do:

```
<textarea>Here is the text</textarea>
```

But I cannot find anything to do this with the HTML Helper. I have tried the following:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment, new { @value = "Text here" })
```

..and a few variations. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comment)
```

is fine. The model you pass along to the view needs to have text in the `Comment` property for the text to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value in the `ViewBag` from the controller side. Just set a property that matches the name of the model property, e.g.:

```
ViewBag.Comment = "Enter text here..."
```

Comment: It's pretty cool if this works, nice not to have to initialize the model. I just don't like how it isn't strong typed.